# Solve Bernouilli differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think that my question is dumb... but I am stuck in a step.

I need to solve this ode: $$\rho' = \rho(1+\rho^2)$$

I made the variable change $u:=\rho^{-2}$. Then, separating variables and replace $u$ by $\rho^{-2}$, i get $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2t}-1}}$.

But, when i check the solution, the result is: $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2t}-1+\color{red}{\frac{1}{\rho_{0}^2}e^{-2t}}}}$.

I think i forget in some integration step the term "$+C$"... I don't know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explicitly write out your separated variables (all $\rho$s on one side and all $t$s on the other side) and then show how you integrated each side?

Comment: Yeah! Ode expressed with the change results: $-2u'=-2\frac{du}{dt}=u+1$, separating $-2\int{\frac{du}{u+1}}=dt$, by integrating both sides: $-2Ln|u+1|=t$, thus $u=e^{-2t}-1$. Expressed in terms of $\rho$: $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2t}-1}}$. I try to put $u_{0}$ in lower limit integration but not works..

Comment: Do you *really* believe the antiderivative with respect to $t$ of $\mathrm{d}t$ is $t$?  Or is it $t+C_1$?  (Subscript, because the other antiderivative *also* has a constant of integration, although you can algebraically combine these two constants into one.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem as stated does not specify any initial datum; therefore let us stipulate

$\rho_0 = \rho(x_0). \tag 0$

We transform the given equation

$\rho' = \rho(\rho^2 + 1) \tag 1$

into

$\dfrac{\rho'}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = 1; \tag 2$

we can integrate the left-hand side by first decomposing $1/(\rho(\rho^2 + 1))$ *via* a partial fraction expansion; writing

$\dfrac{1}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = \dfrac{A}{\rho} + \dfrac{B\rho}{\rho^2 + 1}, \tag 3$

we find

$\dfrac{1}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = \dfrac{A(\rho^2 + 1)}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{B\rho^2}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = \dfrac{(A + B)\rho^2 + A}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)}; \tag 4$

thus,

$A = 1, \tag 5$

$A + B = 0, \tag 6$

and hence

$B = -1; \tag 7$

(3) then becomes

$\dfrac{1}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = \dfrac{1}{\rho} - \dfrac{\rho}{\rho^2 + 1}, \tag 8$

by virtue of which (2) may easily be integrated by elementary means; we have

$\displaystyle \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{d\rho}{\rho(\rho^2 + 1)} = \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{d\rho}{\rho} - \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{\rho d\rho}{\rho^2 + 1} = \int_{x_0}^x dx = x - x_0, \tag 9$

$\displaystyle \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{d\rho}{\rho} = \ln \rho - \ln \rho_0 = \ln \left(\dfrac{\rho}{\rho_0} \right), \tag{10}$

$\displaystyle \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{\rho d\rho}{\rho^2 + 1} = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \dfrac{2\rho d\rho}{\rho^2 + 1}$
$= \dfrac{1}{2} \left (\ln (\rho^2 + 1) - \ln (\rho_0^2 + 1) \right ) = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln \left (\dfrac{\rho^2 + 1}{\rho_0^2 + 1} \right ); \tag{11}$

we substitute (10) and (11) into (9):

$\ln \left(\dfrac{\rho}{\rho_0} \right) - \dfrac{1}{2} \ln \left (\dfrac{\rho^2 + 1}{\rho_0^2 + 1} \right ) = x - x_0, \tag{12}$

and the rest is just algebraic maneuvering:

$\dfrac{1}{2}\ln \left(\dfrac{\rho^2}{\rho_0^2} \right) - \dfrac{1}{2} \ln \left (\dfrac{\rho^2 + 1}{\rho_0^2 + 1} \right ) = x - x_0, \tag{13}$

$\dfrac{1}{2} \ln \left (\dfrac{\rho^2(\rho_0^2 + 1)}{\rho_0^2(\rho^2 + 1)} \right ) = x - x_0, \tag{14}$

$\ln \left (\dfrac{\rho^2(\rho_0^2 + 1)}{\rho_0^2(\rho^2 + 1)} \right ) = 2(x - x_0), \tag{15}$

$\dfrac{\rho^2(\rho_0^2 + 1)}{\rho_0^2(\rho^2 + 1)} = e^{2(x - x_0)}; \tag{16}$

$\dfrac{\rho^2}{\rho^2 + 1} = \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}; \tag{17}$

$\rho^2 = \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}\rho^2 + \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}; \tag{18}$

$\rho^2 \left (1 - \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)} \right) = \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}; \tag{19}$

$\rho^2 = \dfrac{\dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}}{1 - \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{\rho_0^2 + 1}e^{2(x - x_0)}}; \tag{20}$

$\rho^2 = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\rho_0^2 + 1}{\rho_0^2}e^{-2(x - x_0)} - 1} = \dfrac{\rho_0^2}{(\rho_0^2 + 1)e^{-2(x - x_0)} - \rho_0^2} ;\tag{21}$

$\rho = \sqrt{\dfrac{\rho_0^2}{(\rho_0^2 + 1)e^{-2(x - x_0)} - \rho_0^2}} = \dfrac{\rho_0}{\sqrt{(\rho_0^2 + 1)e^{-2(x - x_0)} - \rho_0^2}}; \tag{22}$

we note this agrees with (1) when $x - x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Let $y = \rho$ for writing convenience. To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
y' = y(1+y^{2}) & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{y(1+y^{2})} = 1
\end{align*}
Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y(1+y^{2})} = \frac{(1 + y^{2}) - y^{2}}{y(1+y^{2})} = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{y}{1+y^{2}}
\end{align*}

Finally, we obtain the solution by integrating both sides:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(1+y^{2})} = \int1\mathrm{d}x & \Longleftrightarrow \ln|y| - \frac{\ln(1+y^{2})}{2} = x + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln(y^{2}) - \ln(1+y^{2}) = 2x + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln\left(\frac{y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}\right) = 2x + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y^{2}}{1+y^{2}} = \exp(2x+k)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y^{2}(1 - \exp(2x+k)) = \exp(2x+k)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y^{2} = \frac{\exp(2x+k)}{1-\exp(2x+k)}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y = \pm\left(\frac{\exp(2x+k)}{1-\exp(2x+k)}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}

In order to determine $k$, apply the initial condition $y(0) = y_{0}$.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That's a good idea to solve this type of equation! But i don't get the red part

Answer (score 0):

In your original path, you should, as you found out, apply some integration constant to indefinite integrals or compute all in definite integrals. Then you should arrive at
$$
(ρ^{-2})'=-2ρ^{-3}ρ'=-2(ρ^{-2}+1)\\
\log(ρ^{-2}+1)-\log(ρ_0^{-2}+1)=-2t
\\
\implies
(ρ^{-2}+1)=e^{-2t}(ρ_0^{-2}+1)
$$
which then can be transformed into the solution formula
$$
ρ(t)=\frac{ρ_0}{\sqrt{e^{-2t}(ρ_0^2+1)-ρ_0^2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you! I managed to get the solution that they asked me

\begin{align}
−\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{dt} &= u+1 \\
\iff -\frac{1}{2} \int_{u_{0}}^{u}{\frac{1}{u+1}} &=\int dt \\
\iff \ln|u+1|-\ln|u_{0}+1| &= -2t \\
\iff u+1 &= e^{-2t}(u_{0}+1)
\end{align}

Thus, undoing $u:=\rho^2$, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{\rho^2}=e^{-2t} \left(\frac{1}{\rho_{0}^2}+1 \right)-1 \iff \rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2t}-1+\color{green}{e^{-2t}\frac{1}{\rho_{0}^2}}}}$$

Again, many thanks!